# Unable to center an object to the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a "Sign Up" box to the center of the screen, but whatever I try, everything stays to the left of the page. At the moment it's the "Main Content" that I'm trying to center.

[image: What it looks like]

In my .html and style.css I have the following:

```css
.signbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="singbox">
  <h2>Main Content</h2>
  <p>Other info about the site goes here</p>
</div>
```

I have used this website for the solution, but as you can see from the screenshot, it's not working. -> https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Comment: You have `singbox` and `.signbox` it's just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make spelling correct `singbox` to `signbox`

```css
.signbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="signbox">
        <h2>Main Content</h2>
        <p>Other info about the site goes here</p>
 </div>
```